# How to convert a String xml into a XML node XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I´m consuming the Banxico Web Services and it returns a string, inside that string there is the XML.

What I really need is to extract the next part using XSLT or XPath.

How can do it using XSLT or Xpath?

> Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones
>   denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX)"
>   IDSERIE="SF43718" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio"
>   BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="PesoxDoll">

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace="http://opnet.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">pid=4468,requestid=4d0ce60a-c92f-441e-87b1-4c6f12b26574</X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:tiposDeCambioBanxicoResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx">
         <result xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CompactData xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message"
xmlns:bm="http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact"
xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd
http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact BANXICO_DGIE_SIE_Compact.xsd
http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact SDMXCompactData.xsd" >
    <Header>
        <ID>TIPOSDECAMBIO</ID>
        <Test>false</Test>
        <Truncated>false</Truncated>
        <Name xml:lang="sp">Tipos de Cambio</Name>
        <Prepared>2016-12-15 12:26:37.766</Prepared>
        <Sender id="BANXICO">
            <Name xml:lang="sp">Banco de México</Name>
            <Contact>
            <Name xml:lang="sp">Subgerencia de Desarrollo de Sistemas</Name>
            <Telephone>(01 55)52372678</Telephone>
            </Contact>
        </Sender>
        <DataSetAction>Update</DataSetAction>
        <Extracted>2016-12-15 12:26:37.766</Extracted>
    </Header>
    <bm:DataSet>
        <bm:SiblingGroup BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" TIME_FORMAT="P1D"/>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Tipo de cambio pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de liquidación" IDSERIE="SF60653" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="PesoxDoll">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-15" OBS_VALUE="20.2567"/>
        </bm:Series>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Tipo de cambio                                          Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX)" IDSERIE="SF43718" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="PesoxDoll">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-15" OBS_VALUE="20.5973"/>
        </bm:Series>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Cotización de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Euro" IDSERIE="SF46410" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="Peso">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-14" OBS_VALUE="21.535"/>
        </bm:Series>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Cotización de la divisa Respecto al peso mexicano Dólar Canadiense" IDSERIE="SF60632" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="Peso">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-14" OBS_VALUE="15.4178"/>
        </bm:Series>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Cotización de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Yen japonés" IDSERIE="SF46406" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="Peso">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-14" OBS_VALUE="0.176"/>
        </bm:Series>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Cotización de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Libra esterlina" IDSERIE="SF46407" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="Peso">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-14" OBS_VALUE="25.5806"/>
        </bm:Series>
    </bm:DataSet>
</CompactData>]]></result>
      </ns1:tiposDeCambioBanxicoResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With that response I build a xsd schema.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SiblingGroup">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="BANXICO_FREQ"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:duration" name="TIME_FORMAT"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Series" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Obs">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="TIME_PERIOD" use="optional"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="OBS_VALUE" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="TITULO" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="IDSERIE" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="BANXICO_FREQ" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT or XPath can you use? As the inner XML is escaped as a CDATA section you need two parsing steps, if you want to do that in pure XSLT or XPath then you need XSLT/XPath 3.0 or an implementation that supports an extension to parse XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just run an XSL transformation to extract the information you want, you don't need to generate a schema.

If you can use XPath 3 functions, you can do all of this in one pass: XPath 3 includes a function to parse a string and turn it into a logical XML tree, allowing you to then run XPath expressions against that.

If you can't use XPath 3 functions, then you'll need to do this in two passes: export just the `<result>` text content (the XML response that you want to further process) to a separate file, and then load that file and run another transform on that to extract what you want.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example of how to process this in one pass using XPath 3.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Start at the document node / and set up the outermost element -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Change this element name to whatever makes sense for you -->
        <BanxicoReply>
            <!-- The input file only has one "result", 
                and that's all we want, so grab it -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//result"/>
        </BanxicoReply>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <!-- Parse the CDATA content to turn it into XML -->
        <xsl:variable name="contained-xml" select="parse-xml(./text())"/>

        <!-- Do what you need to here.
            This example just plucks out the one chunk
            you identified at the top of your post. 

            Note the "*:Series" shorthand: this matches
            any "Series" element in any namespace.  This 
            is an admittedly sloppy shortcut, which could
            be dangerous in other contexts - but here, in
            this one file, it's safe, and this avoids the 
            need for us to explicitly declare the "bm:" 
            namespace prefix in this XSL. -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$contained-xml//*:Series[@IDSERIE='SF43718']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Suppress output of all other elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your XML above as the input, this XSL produces the following result (indented for easier human legibility):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BanxicoReply>
    <bm:Series xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message" 
        xmlns:bm="http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact" 
        xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        TITULO="Tipo de cambio                                          Pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX)" 
        IDSERIE="SF43718" 
        BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" 
        BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" 
        BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="PesoxDoll">
        <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-12-15" OBS_VALUE="20.5973"/>
    </bm:Series>
</BanxicoReply>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the JSON API https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest instead of that old soap service.